# Magento 2.3: Create custom category attribute with WYSIWYG

Tags: magento2.3, wysiwyg, category-attribute

I want to add WYSIWYG enabled textareas as custom fields for categories. I have read all related topics on this site for this issue, but none of the mentioned answers seem to do the trick. Can somebody see what I'm doing wrong?

Note: This is Magento 2.3 - The module works, the attributes are created properly, data is saved correctly, but the WYSIWYG won't show. The configuration setting for WYSIWYG fields is correct too.

**/app/code/MyCompant/CategoryFields/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Category::ENTITY,
            'sm_category_faq1_content',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'FAQ1 Content',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 102,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**/app/code/MyCompany/CategoryFields/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
    <fieldset name="custom_content">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Content</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="sm_category_faq1_content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">FAQ1 Content</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">250px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">sm_category_faq1_content</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">12</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please check your admin configuration Stores->Configuration->General->Content Management->WYSIWYG Options->Enable WYSIWYG Editor Set to "Disabled By Default" or "Enabled By Default". If it is set to "Disabled Completely" you will get only Textarea

Comment: I also checked that already, that's not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => true,` should be `'wysiwyg_enabled' => true`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/172602)

Comment: How does it not provide an answer? He has code in which I see the issue. And the issue is that he uses is_wysiwyg_enabled instead of wysiwyg_enabled. There is not much explanation to give. That's just how it is

Comment: I agree! My question was "what am I doing wrong" and this answers it just fine. However, I changed this and reinstalled without any change..

Comment: Did you also make sure the field was removed from the database? Just reinstalling the module is not sufficient if the field was still in the database. You should remove the module form the `setup_modules` table to be sure the `setup` script runs again, and the fields should be remove from `eav_attribute` table. Using a back-up of the database is often more quick. Also, you could use `magerun2`, a tool build around `bin/magento` which has a command line command to remove EAV fields from your database through the CLI.

Comment: I figured this too :) I am now trying this. Removing the fields from `eav_attribute` table would be sufficient?

Comment: I added some more info to my previous comment :-)

Comment: I did all this without result sadly. I'm sure the installscript re-ran, but the fields are still without WYSIWYG.

Comment: Could you try with `"type" => "text"`? I've faced exactly the same issue as you did and fixed it with replacing `is_wysiwyg_enabled' => true` to 'wysiwyg_enabled' => true`, so there might be something else going wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103339/discussion-between-alex-timmer-and-kevinvhengst).